# How to optimize declaration of many variables? [Java]

Tags: java, android, arrays, optimization

At the moment I am using this:

```
            d_y1 = Double.parseDouble(s_y1);
            d_y2 = Double.parseDouble(s_y2);
            d_y3 = Double.parseDouble(s_y3);
            d_y4 = Double.parseDouble(s_y4);
            d_y5 = Double.parseDouble(s_y5);
            d_y6 = Double.parseDouble(s_y6);
            d_x1 = Double.parseDouble(s_x1);
            d_x2 = Double.parseDouble(s_x2);
            d_x3 = Double.parseDouble(s_x3);
            d_x4 = Double.parseDouble(s_x4);
            d_x5 = Double.parseDouble(s_x5);
            d_x6 = Double.parseDouble(s_x6);
```

And I thought about something like this, but it wont work:
Any advice?

```
String[] s_Werte = {s_x1, s_x2, s_x3, s_x4, s_x5, s_x6,s_y1, s_y2, s_y3, s_y4, s_y5, s_y6};
double[] d_Werte = {d_x1, d_x2, d_x3, d_x4, d_x5, d_x6,d_y1, d_y2, d_y3, d_y4, d_y5, d_y6};

for (i = 0; i < d_Werte.length; i++){
                d_Werte[i] = Double.parseDouble(s_Werte[i]);
            }
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you have? Do you not like it because it takes up several _lines_ of code?

Comment: What does "but it wont work" mean? What problem do you have? And what is your expectation that is not fulfilled?

Comment: If you change your line to `double[] d_Werte = new double[s_Werte.length];` it should at least do the same as your original code

Comment: the values from the double array are not getting declared with the string values from the string array

Comment: It doesn't work because the values in `d_Werte` are copies of `d_x1, d_x2, ...` not the originals.  So assigning into `d_Werte` won't change `d_x1, d_x2, ...`.  You should just use arrays throughout the code, and dispense with the individual variables entirely.

Comment: and how do I fix that?

Comment: @Feuer1978 look at my solution below, it should solve your current problem?

Comment: @user3437460, sorry your solution (which I see has been deleted now), didn't solve anything - you didn't seem to understand the question.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use array then you cannot initialize it with variables so this won't work:

```
double[] d_Werte = {d_x1, d_x2, d_x3, d_x4, d_x5, d_x6,d_y1, d_y2, d_y3, d_y4, d_y5, d_y6};
```

But also you need to get your String variable in format you can loop into like:

```
String[] strings;
```

You need first to initialize its size (and to allocate the necessary space):

```
double[] d_Werte = new double[12];
```

or use 2 array of 6 length, and then assign each value to the specific index:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
 d_Werte[i] = Double.parseDouble(strings[i]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can have 2 ArrayLists, one contains your strings, and the other can be populated by their double values.

So you can do the work through looping instead of writing a million line of code.

```
List<String> strings ...
List<Double> doubles ...

for (String s : strings) {
    doubles.add(Double.parseDouble(s));
}
```

That way it's dynamic in population and size

Comment: This does not solve the original problem. After the "parseDouble" the originally defined local variables should be used. This does not seem to be possible with `Double`, which is why I suggested creating a wrapper class, which does work.

Comment: "The originally defined local variables", you mean the exact same variable ? what you're suggesting is to have a list of references to primitive type, which java doesn't do // What difference will it make to use the originally defined variable or another that has the same value, since they're primitives ?

Comment: I didn't ask the original question. However if you read the original question, the user wanted to _simplify_ the code into a loop to initialise the local variables, not the replace them. It seems this was a question about how to make the code _look_ _pretty_, which is always a matter of personal taste for each individual programmer.

Comment: Here's the title to the question: "How to optimize declaration of **many variables**?"

Answer (score -3):

Here is a *crazy* solution, I wouldn't really use this, but it shows that (with a workaround) what you tried to does work:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ValueArrays
{
    public static class MyDouble
    {
        public Double value = 0d;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        MyDouble d1 = new MyDouble();
        MyDouble d2 = new MyDouble();
        MyDouble d3 = new MyDouble();
        MyDouble dn = new MyDouble();
        String s1 = "3";
        String s2 = "2";
        String s3 = "1";

        // s_Values and d_Values MUST be of the same length, 
        // whether you use variable or static String's here doesn't matter
        String[] s_Values = { s1, s2, s3, "9.9" };
        List<MyDouble> d_Values = Arrays.asList(d1, d2, d3, dn);

        for ( int i = 0; i < d_Values.size(); i++ )
        { // This will now initialise all the "local" variables
            d_Values.get(i).value = Double.valueOf(s_Values[i]);
        }

        // As you'll see from the output, all local values have now been correctly "initialised".
        System.out.println("d1 = " + d1.value);
        System.out.println("d2 = " + d2.value);
        System.out.println("d3 = " + d3.value);
        System.out.println("dn = " + dn.value);
    }
}
```

Edit: Please ignore the down votes, this DOES work in regards to the original question: "How to optimize **declaration of many variables**"

Comment: Nothing in the post suggests that he needs to use the same exact variables, he just needs a neater way to do this without writing too many lines.

Comment: @MahmoudElmorabea, read the question again and take a good look at his code ... it WORKS, why would he claim it doesn't if he wasn't trying to use the original local variables are the `for` loop?